# Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt

Tags: windows-server-2003

We are running Windows Server 2003 R2 with SP2. When I login I get the following messagebox twice

"Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."

Below are the steps I have tried and still get the error when I login
Disabled all Non-Microsoft Service and reboot the server
Disabled all startup items from msconfig and reboot the server
Repaired .Net Framework 3.5 SP1

There are no event in either Application of System log indicating the cause of the error message

My question is how do I stop these error messages and find out which application is throwing them. Are there utilities out there to diagnose the problem.

Thanks for your help and helping a newbie to the IT Field

Juzer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get the messagebox on the screen, if you bring up task manager, and then select go to process, you should be able to see the process responsible for the display of the messagebox. That is to say from the "Applications" tab select the messagebox in task manager and then select go to process

Comment: Tried your suggestion, the Application tab is completly empty and the message box is open.

Comment: Lets try one more way to get the process responsible. Download WinSpy++ from [link](http://www.catch22.net/software/winspy-17). When you see the messagebox on the screen, run WinSpy.exe (from the above zip), and drag the finder tool cursor and release it on the messagebox. Once you release it, on the messagebox, you will see a process tab, if you go to the process tab, you should see the process responsible for the messagebox.

Comment: Excellent Suggestion, that is what I was looking for. I was able to find the program which was causing the error dialog box to popup with the help of WinSpy++. But the question now arises that what is causing the program to run. I checked the startup in msconfig, registry, Program startup, task scheduler and no where do I see the program being launched. The program which winspy++ detected is a program which we use in our other offices also everyday so it also not a spyware, malware etc. I already ran Malwarebyte, Antivirus, RootKit detectors and everything came out clean.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I now have one step less in trying to reach a resolution. Sorry for the late response as I have the flu bug

Comment: How do I accept the response from stamhaney as an acceptable answer